# Is there a way to add code to HTML from other files?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a multi page website which uses the same navbar and everytime I want to change something to it I have to copy and paste everything that I have done to the other HTML files.Is there a way to have only one file where the code for the navbar is located and just import it to the other HTML files so when I change something to it, it also changes to all the other files ? (much like a React Component)

Comment: Are you asking how to use [the script element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)?

Comment: What have you tried?  There's no native HTML way to do this, but you can [find hacks](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) that achieve what you're describing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is "Yes" you can do it without React also. Look for the previous version of **w3.js**

see this example of how they are including

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/content.html

into another page

here is the existing working sample

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_include_2